# Nodejs Multiple map arrays to single Json file

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, dictionary

I'm new to nodejs and am trying to write a Json parser that will take data from a Json API, allow me to grab the data I want (some of this data I will transform) and then write to a Json file.

I have discovered the map command which is extracting the raw data and this is giving me an array for example

```
        data['home_team'] = json['data'].map(smdata => smdata.localTeam.data.name);
        data['awayid'] = json['data'].map(smdata => smdata.visitorTeam.data.id);
        data['away_team'] = json['data'].map(smdata => smdata.visitorTeam.data.name);
```

And this works perfectly, now I'm left with an array which I want to turn into a Json file, I can of course just run a FOR loop and iterate through each of the entries and write to a file but I wondered if there was a more efficent way to do this

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to turn your data into a string you can write to a file.

In your comments below, you provide an invalid JS structure, an array with keys - maybe a typo with square braces (array) rather than curly braces (object). Or maybe note that [Array map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns an array, so you may wish to look at [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), depending on your data.

```js
let data = {
  islive: [90, 90, null, null],
  ls: [1, 1, 1, 1],
  time: [90, 90, null, null],
  status: ['FT', 'FT', 'NS', 'NS'],
  starttime: [1616036700, 1616050800, 1616058000, 1616058900],
  matchid: [17706353, 17926675, 17869155, 17926676]
};

// Dump it as JSON:
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

// Pretty print with 2 space indent:
console.log(JSON.stringify(data, {}, 2));

// Write it to file 'my.json':
const fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFileSync(
  'my.json', 
  JSON.stringify(data)
);
```

Outputs:

```
{"islive":[90,90,null,null],"ls":[1,1,1,1],"time":[90,90,null,null],"status":["FT","FT","NS","NS"],"starttime":[1616036700,1616050800,1616058000,1616058900],"matchid":[17706353,17926675,17869155,17926676]}

{
  "islive": [
    90,
    90,
    null,
    null
  ],
  "ls": [
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1
  ],
  "time": [
    90,
    90,
    null,
    null
  ],
  "status": [
    "FT",
    "FT",
    "NS",
    "NS"
  ],
  "starttime": [
    1616036700,
    1616050800,
    1616058000,
    1616058900
  ],
  "matchid": [
    17706353,
    17926675,
    17869155,
    17926676
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi Lee, sadly that just gives me an empty set []

My data array which ive created if I dump to the log looks like this

`code`
[
  islive: [ 90, 90, null, null ],
  ls: [ 1, 1, 1, 1 ],
  time: [ 90, 90, null, null ],
  status: [ 'FT', 'FT', 'NS', 'NS' ],
  starttime: [ 1616036700, 1616050800, 1616058000, 1616058900 ],
  matchid: [ 17706353, 17926675, 17869155, 17926676 ],
]`code`

Comment: @MikeHobson - if you `console.log(data)` before you stringify, is there data?

Comment: Yes I see an array as below 
`[
  islive: [ 90, 90, null, null ],
  ls: [ 1, 1, 1, 1 ],
  time: [ 90, 90, null, null ],
  status: [ 'FT', 'FT', 'NS', 'NS' ],
  starttime: [ 1616036700, 1616050800, 1616058000, 1616058900 ],
  matchid: [ 17706353, 17926675, 17869155, 17926676 ]]`

Comment: @MikeHobson That's not a valid Javascript data structure -- if you replace the outermost `[square braces]` with `{curly braces}`, to create an *object* rather than an *array*, you should be fine. Array's cannot have keys in Javascript, but objects (associative arrays) can.

Comment: Hi Lee, Im not creating the structure, its being created by several Map statements

`data['time'] = json['data'].map(smdata => smdata.time.minute);  
data['status'] = json['data'].map(smdata => smdata.time.status);  `

I then console.log(data) so the square brackets are denoting this is an array

Comment: `the square brackets are denoting this is an array` -- but it is not a plain array, it is an associative array, because it has keys. In JS, that's called an object, and *must* be surrounded with curly brackets.

Your code `data['home_team']` is accessing the `home_team` field of the object. (Such is usually written as `data.home_team`.). That creates `{home_team: ...}`, where my ellipsis represents the value of that entry, which *is* an array coming from your use of `map`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230067/discussion-between-mike-hobson-and-lee-goddard).